# Excel 2013 64 : how to import a C string (null terminated) from external dll

Tags: string, excel, dll, import

I ask for a simple vba code to import a C string (null terminated) into Excel 2013 64

I have a C dll (compiled with Visual Studio 2015 for x64, strings set to Multi-byte) which exports several methods like this

```
__declspec(dllexport) char *MyMsg()
{
return(mymsg);
}
```

(function body is much more complex)

when working with C, C#, VB net codes etc. I have no problems to call these methods,

some, as C# , may require some additional conversion but methods work and don't crash (most important),

```
[DllImport(@"D:\my.dll", EntryPoint = "mymsg", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
        internal static extern string ErrMsg()
```

with old versions of Excel I was able to import as string (stable solution, no problems at all)

however it seems that with Office 2013 developers have modified some things and the old methods now, in Excel 2013 64 (and 2016), can generate exceptions stopping working,

I have tested different vba code (for example the code suggested to import from system dll) with very limited success,
std. debugging tools as Windbg etc. may report memory corruption or equivalent critical exceptions.

I have also considered to modify the C code in order to export a different object but I noticed that Variants in Excel 2013 64 may become very unstable possibly due to different deallocation policy, so I stopped this way,
honestly, as very personal opinion I am reluctant to adopt OLE objects and I would prefer to maintain the actual code in C dll,

your help will be very appreciated,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a quick update about this question,
discussing the topic with other developers
I decided to test the way suggested by Microsoft, 
calling from VBA and passing a pointer to a String,
herebelow the C code for the two alternatives which I have tested,
I regret to say that in both cases when stressed Excel 2013 64 stops generating an allocation error in VBE7 module (detected by Windbg and Visual Studio 2015) 
by the way, the same works fine with Excel 2010 64 and there is little to add...
now, if some microsoft expert can help suggesting a C++ code tested with Excel 2013 64 that will be very appreciated,
differently I would suppose there is something not working as expected (at least in my copy of) Excel 2013 64

```
__declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI mymsg(BSTR *vbstr)

const char *lpszA = "test Excel 2013 64";

// Alternative 1
// SysFreeString(*vbstr);
// int nLen  = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,lpszA,strlen(lpszA),0,0);
// *vbstr = SysAllocStringLen(0,nLen);
// MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,lpszA,strlen(lpszA),*vbstr,nLen);

// alternative 2
SysFreeString(*vbstr);
int nLen  = strlen(lpszA);
wchar_t *lpszW = new wchar_t[nLen+1]; 
mbstowcs( lpszW, lpszA, nLen+1); 
*vbstr = SysAllocString(lpszW);
delete[] lpszW; 
}
```